# a question about finitely generated modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $M$ be an $R-$module. Let $R^n$ be the direct sum of $n$ copies of $R$. Prove that if there is a surjective $R-$homomorphism $\pi:R^n\to M$ then $M$ is finitely generated.
Clearly $R^n$ is finitely generated and because of $\pi$ we have that $|M|\le|R^n|$. This should be enough to get the thesis but I can't formally prove it. 
Thank you.

Comment: Prove that the image of the canonical basis of $R^n$ generate $M$.

Comment: You can't use cardinality to argue finite generation.  For example, if $R$ is countable, then so is $\bigoplus_{n\in \mathbb N}R$, but this is not finitely generated.

Comment: Roland in order to prove what you said, $\pi$ shouldn't be an homomorphism? Otherwise,  could you give me some details please?

Comment: @Richard For this proposition to be true, $\pi$ can't be any map. It has to be $R$-homomorphism. With what Aaron said, you can see that two $R$-modules can be in bijection, but one being of finite type and not the other.

Comment: Roland ok if $\pi$ must be $R-homomorphism$ then it is clear: let $m\in M$ then there is $r\in R^n$ such that $\pi(r)=\pi(x_1e_1+...+x_ne_n)=m$, namely $x_1\pi(e_1)+...+x_n\pi(e_n)=m$ whence the thesis. Do you agree?

Comment: @Richard Yes this is it ;)

Comment: You're welcome !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, it holds that if $N$ is a finitely generated $R$-module and $M$ is an $R$-module, such that there exists $f: N \to M$, a surjective homomorphism of $R$-modules, then $M$ is finitely generated:

Let $\{x_1,...,x_n\}$ be a SOGs of $N$. For $y \in M$, there exists $x \in N$ for which $y = f(x)$. For $x$, there are $r_1,...,r_n \in R$ such that $x = \sum r_i x_i$. Hence $y = f(\sum r_i x_i) = \sum r_i f(x_i)$, and so $\{f(x_1),...,f(x_n)\}$ is a SOGs of $M$.